# Function with variable arguments in pthread_create()?

Tags: c, pthreads

How to implement a function with variable arguments (n arguments) like: void *thre(int, ... );, inside pthread_create(&thr, NULL, thre , ???)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want, but the solution is probably to use the fundamental theorem of software engineering: add a level of indirection.

Comment: NVM, think I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototype for the thread handler function is set. It must be `void* (*)(void*)`. You cannot pass a function that accepts something else, even with casting, since that will be the cause of undefined behavior.

But POSIX allows you a single `void*` parameter, which is enough to pass the address of anything, and therefore not that limiting.

So if you want to pass some extra parameters, bundle them in a structure:

```
struct my_data {
  int    n;
  char   c;
  double d;
};

void *variable_argument_function (int first_arg, ...) {
  return NULL;
}

void* handler(void *vdata) {
  struct my_data *data = vdata;

  return variable_argument_function(data->n,
                                    data->c,
                                    data->d);
  //use data->n, data->c, data->d
}

int main(void) {
  struct my_data t_data = {
    .n = 1, .c = 'a', .d = 3.14
  };

  pthread_t t;
  if (pthread_create(&t, NULL, &handler, &t_data) == 0)
    pthread_join(t, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @YasserNezzari - If I gather correctly, then yes. Just do as I did in my updated code piece.

Comment: Thank you very much that's what I needed !